# How to convert a python palette to an array of colors of a given size?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

It needs to fill the space between the 10 graphs that take place above each other with the function

```
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color= 'here_is_color', alpha=0.5)
```

The colors should change, for example, from red to blue from top to bottom. To do this, I think you can convert a given palette to a color array and use it in a loop until the space between the graphs is filled.

[image: The photo shows an example of what should happen:]

Comment: @PatrickArtner Sorry, I'm new here, I haven't found the answer to this question anywhere. To be more precise, it needs to fill the space between the 10 graphs that take place above each other with the function specified earlier. The colors should change, for example, from green to yellow from top to bottom. To do this, I think you can create an color-array and use it in loop, which infill the space between graphs

Comment: you might want to [edit] your post with a minimal example of the graphs you get and what you want :o)

Comment: @PatrickArtner ok, done:-)

Answer (score 1):

I share the solution I found:)

```
col = cm.get_cmap('RdBu', size)
num=1.0
```

Next, change the num counter in the loop as needed, the function will look like

```
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color=col(num))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the color palettes defined for matplit-lib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors 
import numpy as np
```

Get the colors and sort them by hsv (or supply the names in the order you want - see [matplotlib.org named_colors.html example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/named_colors.html)

```
def get_hsv_colors():
    # https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/named_colors.html
    by_hsv = sorted((tuple(mcolors.rgb_to_hsv(mcolors.to_rgb(color))), name) 
                    for name, color in mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.items())
    return [name for _, name in by_hsv]
```

Create some demo data for stacked `y`'s:

```
def get_y_data():
    y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6 = np.random.rand(6,20) 
    y2 += y1   + 0.01
    y3 += y2   + 0.01
    y4 += y3   + 0.01
    y5 += y4   + 0.01
    y6 += y5   + 0.01
    return y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6
```

Plug it together:

```
# get the color-names from above or supply your own names:
cols_to_use = get_hsv_colors()[20::5] # skip the greys, only take every 5th name 

# zipp the data with the corresponding color
matched_y_data = list( zip((y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6), cols_to_use))

# plot data with lines
for (y,c) in matched_y_data:
    plt.plot(x, y, color=c)

plt.show()

# plot the same using fill_between 

fig, ax1  = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(6, 6))

# base line  y -> 0:
ax1.fill_between(x, matched_y_data[0][0], 0, color=matched_y_data[0][1]) 

# intermediate lines y_n -> y_n+1:
for (idx, (y_data, col)) in enumerate(matched_y_data[:-1]):
    ax1.fill_between(x, y_data, matched_y_data[idx+1][0], color=col)

# last line 
mm = max( matched_y_data[-1][0] ) + 0.1
ax1.fill_between(x, matched_y_data[-1][0], mm, color=matched_y_data[-1][1]) 

ax1.set_xlabel('x')

fig.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

to get

[image: just plotted lines]

and

[image: filled images]

---

You can get your colorscheme by carefully choosing your color names:

```
# zipp the data with the corresponding color
matched_y_data = list( 
    zip((y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6), 
        "royalblue cornflowerblue lightsteelblue mistyrose lightsalmon tomato".split()))
```

[image: blue red scheme]

Comment: Thank you a lot!